# How to filter dropdown data in SocialEngine sign up form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I am working with Social Engine which is based on Zend Framework and Smarty Templates.

I have created two custom drop down fields "Country" and "City" in sign up form using SocailEngine admin panel.
I want to know, is there any way to filter the data in City dropdown based on selected Country?

I know how to implement this feature using simple AJAX and PHP, but I want to know how to do this using SocialEngine admin panel and what is the best way to do this in a ScocialEngine based application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way to do this, here are the details:

1. In admin panel, click 'Profile Fields' in Global Settings sections.
2. Add a new field Country in fields tree.
3. There is a "Field Type", change it from Text Field to Pull down Select Box.
4. Scroll down to Options section, click 'Add New Option' link.
5. Add country name in Label field. In dependency box, choose Yes and type 'City' in Dependent Field Label box.
6. Repeat step 5 for all countries you want to add in your signup form.
7. Click Edit Field button to save changes.
8. In fields tree, you will see a sub tree under Country field. All countries will be visible in this tree with Dependent Field link.
9. Click Dependent Field link against a country and make it a drop down and populate it with cities in that specific country.
10. Repeat Step 9 for all countries.

It will take time but it is a one time effort and you will get what you need without modifying the code.